# Headers not working, no error

Tags: php, header

My headers are not working at all now and no response is been shown 
My php file looks like this

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ob_start();
session_start();
require('../in/connect.php');
require ('../password.php');
if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
  $username = stripslashes($_POST['user']);
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username);
  $username = str_replace(" ", "_",$username);
  $password = stripslashes($_POST['pass']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
  $email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$email);
  $date = $_POST['date'];
  if (($date != '') && ($email != '') && ($password != '') && ($username != '')) {
  $passwordnew = (password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
  $trn_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  $query = "INSERT into `users` (username, email, password, trn_date, birth_date)
         VALUES ('".$username."', '".$email."', '$passwordnew', '$trn_date','$date')";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
          if ($result){
            $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `users` where username = '".$username."'");
            $user = $sql->fetch_assoc();
        $id = $user['id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        header("location:./");
        }
}
}
?>
```

The entry I been made and the session variables too but no redirect and no error in the logs.
Already checked this thread [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: Are you actually flushing the output buffer? I'm not seeing `ob_flush()` ...

Comment: check the error_log are you on local or on a domain?

Comment: Its,empty @AviTeller

Comment: follow what CD001 said

Comment: 1. You have an sql injection problem, you should use prepared statements, 2. You should never store the users password in the session, 3. Have you tried redirecting to a complete url? 4. Why are you manipulating the users password?

Comment: I don't think I have a sql injection problem. tell me where it is @jeroen

Comment: `$date` is not safe.

Comment: its a input type date . I'll see to it anyways @IncredibleHat

Comment: `$date = $_POST['date'];` ... anyone can pass anything in on that :( So its better to safegaurd it. But all of this could be done easier with prepares (but thats outside the topic... since this is about your ob_start).

Comment: removed `OB_start` still nothing

Comment: instead of header redirect please use javascript redirect like below echo '<script>window.location='yourpagename'</script>' might be header redirect not working beucase included file content echo statement.

Comment: Using `ob_start()` is fine to avoid sending the headers in case of output that would cause your `header()` call to fail. You should probably turn it off during development, but that is not the problem here.

Comment: Silly question: Have you checked your browsers dev tools 'network' tab, and see that its not returning as a Server code 500?

Comment: what should be the location of the header? -- i mean 'send to page'

Comment: @IncredibleHat can you tell me again the things you wanted me to put at the top of the script

Comment: Useful for debugging (not for 500 errors though) `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your query

$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `users` where username = '".$username."'");

$user = $sql->fetch_assoc();

not throwing any mysql error

if it will throw the error
header will not work.
Because before header we can not print anything

Comment: this is strange as soon as I put a header function, the signup post request is not being made like the code below `if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {` is not executed

Comment: the query is fine